# Importing data from distance matrix into mysql table

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following distance matrix in csv format.

http://palaeomath.palass.org/images/mds/T1.jpg

Using PHP, how could I import this data into a MYSQL table with the columns city1, city2, distance?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP has the hability to [parse CSV](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) and [store data as an array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php).
So once the CSV has been converted into PHP array, you use that array to construct `INSERT` sentences to your DB.